# SDL2 program eats a lot of memory when minimized

Tags: c++, memory, rendering, sdl, sdl-2

I'm just trying to create a simple SDL2 window with a simple renderer. When I debug it, it runs normally, the memory still normal. But when I minimize it, press the minimize button then suddenly the memory just keep going up and only when i reopened that window then the memory goes back normal.

[Memory spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PWoN.png)

The code:

```cpp
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    SDL_Window* gWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* gRenderer;
    SDL_Texture* gTexture;
    SDL_Surface* temp;
    //Init
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1366, 768, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    //loading medias
    temp = IMG_Load("assets/sprites/700.png");
    gTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, temp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

    //The main loop
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }

    //Destroy things
    SDL_DestroyTexture(gTexture);
    gTexture = NULL;   
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (m_event.window.event)
{
case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED:
    while (SDL_WaitEvent(&m_event))
    {
        if (m_event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESTORED)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
...
```

So when you minimize the Window, SDL keeps waiting for events. No further code could memory leak, since it stays in the lazy polling loop until the window is restored.
I traced the leak back to SDL_RenderClear, which shouldn't be supposed to run while minimized.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and compiled it. Seems fine. However you did mention when you minimize the program your ram meter increases, how long are you able to perform this repetition before it crashes? and does it even crash? It could be normal behavior. If your program crashes, its a memory leak which could indicate forgetting to de-allocate some other pointer to a memory object/variable.